# What's the shortcut to delete a word "forward" in a unix terminal?

Tags: terminal, osx

I do `Ctrl+W` in the mac terminal to delete a word (deletes from where the cursor is at to the beginning of the word)

How do I do the opposite - deletes from where the cursor is to the end of the word?

Answer (score 33):

This depends on your shell and its active command line editing mode.

For a shell with Emacs command line editing mode (`set -o emacs` in some shells), use <kbd>Alt+D</kbd> (this doesn't work on macOS for whatever reason, but prints the character `∂`, use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> instead).

For a shell with Vi command line editing mode (`set -o vi` in some shells), use <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>dw</kbd> (this *does* work on macOS as well).

Comment: Only in zsh though does Meta-D delete the same type of _word_ that Ctrl-W does (blank delimited ones). In `bash` in `vi` mode, you can use `dW` to delete those

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, they (the two keycombos) have a different view of what constitutes a "word".

Comment: You can check the "use option as meta" in the terminal Keyboard preferences to make it work.

Comment: Both Esc+D and Alt+D work in *xfce4 terminal 0.6.3*.

Answer (score 18):

In the Linux terminal, you can try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete from the cursor to the end of the line.

There are few other shortcuts such as:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>: move the cursor to the end of the line.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>: flip the two characters around the cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>: yank the text from the kill ring (paste previously deleted text).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>: delete the text from the start of the line to the cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>: submit the current line and load the next line from history (if any).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>: fetch the previous line from history (like <kbd>↑</kbd>).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>: delete the the rest of the line after the cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>: move the cursor to the beginning of the line.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>: if the line is empty, equivalent to `EOF`; typically, exit the shell. Otherwise, delete the character after the cursor.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>: move the cursor forward by one character.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>: same as <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>: same as <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>: same as <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>: same as <kbd>→</kbd>.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>: delete the word to the left of the cursor.

Answer (score 3):

For the tty line discipline, `^W` deletes the previous white-space delimited *word*.

In the `vi` editor in insert mode, `^W` deletes backward to the start of the first sequence of alnums or non-alnums (on `foo-+-bar.. baz`, it first deletes `baz`, then `..`, then `bar`, then `-+-`, then `foo`).

In the `emacs` editor, `^W` deletes from the cursor position to the *mark* (the one you set with <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>).

Some line editors like `readline` (used by `bash`, `gdb`...), `zle` (used by `zsh`), `pdksh`'s when in `vi` mode, behave like `vi` in that regard and when in `emacs` mode behave like the tty line discipline (not `emacs`).

`libedit` (used by BSD shells or (optionally) `dash`), `tcsh`, AT&T `ksh`, in `emacs` mode, behave like `emacs` where `^W` deletes to the *mark* (initially at the beginning of the buffer).

For deleting a word forward, in the `vi` editor, you'd do it in *command* (*normal*) mode with `dw` to delete to the beginning of the next sequence of alnums or non-alnums (or the end of the line) and `dW` to delete to the  next sequence of non-blanks (the pendant of the `^W` of the tty line discipline).

In the `emacs` line editor, <kbd>Meta-D</kbd> would delete to the *end* of the next sequence of alnum characters. The word motion operators (<kbd>Meta-B</kbd>, <kbd>Meta-F</kbd>) behave similarly.

command line editors, when in `vi` mode, behave like `vi`, but in `emacs` mode, you have two main schools: the `tcsh` school and the `ksh` school.

The `ksh` school (`readline`, `ksh`, `yash`) behaves mostly like `emacs` (`fish`'s behaviour is slightly different in how it treats non-alnum, non-whitespace characters in both `emacs` and `vi` mode).

In the `tcsh` school (`tcsh`, `libedit`, `zsh`), word motions are based on whitespace-delimited words so are consistent with the tty line discipline's `^W` in that regard.

In `zsh`, the behaviour is [customizable](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Widgets-1) with different *word styles* for all the word motion widgets.

For `readline`, you can get the `tcsh` school (and have <kbd>Meta-D</kbd> delete the same kind of word as <kbd>Ctrl-W</kbd> does) by adding to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
set keymap vi-move
"\e[EMACS~": emacs-editing-mode
set keymap emacs
"\e[VI~": vi-movement-mode
"\ed": "\e[VI~dW\e[EMACS~"
"\ef": vi-fWord
"\eb": vi-bWord
```

Or on the other hand, align `^W` to the other word motion widgets (behave like <kbd>Meta-Backscape</kbd>) with:

```
set keymap emacs
"\C-W": backward-kill-word
```

As to what the <kbd>Meta</kbd> key is, see [there](/a/368871).