# iTerm2 - Deleting an entire word until whitespace

Tags: zsh, macos, iterm2

I have my iTerm2 configured with a shortcut to delete a word (keyboard mapping of Hex code 0x17).
However, I want it to delete until reaching a whitespace:

Current:
`cd hello-world` -> `cd hello-`

Wanted:
`cd hello-world` -> `cd`

Is there a way to configure the non-word separators somehow? Or to achieve this by other means?

Comment: You are using `zsh`, right? I believe that is the default on macOS these days. Please edit your question adn add that in (if you don't know, look at the output of `ps -p $$`, does it mention `bash` or `zsh`?

Comment: Does this answer you question? [zsh keybindings: make backward-kill-word act on whole quoted string](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/665461)

Comment: Also tangentally related: [What's the shortcut to delete a word "forward" in a unix terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/394418)

Comment: Thanks! I added `zsh` tag - also, @Kusalananda - the link you provided seemed to solve it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Kusalananda - This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665559/558580) seems to do it:
Adding the following to the `.zshrc` file:

```
autoload -U select-word-style
select-word-style whitespace
```